# Where is TypeScript better documented than in the "Handbook" documentation?

Tags: typescript, documentation

I know the [TypeScript documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook) is not entirely up to date as the `type` and `abstract` keywords are not mentioned.  For example the following is now valid TypeScript:

```
interface A {
    b: string;
}

// I can't see anywhere in documentation this is mentioned.
type C = A;
var d: C;

d.b = 'something';
```

Is there a better place to get up to date documentation apart from parsing the source code or reading all the latest changes on GitHub issues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "type" reserved word in TypeScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364693/what-is-the-type-reserved-word-in-typescript)

Comment: Probably the language spec, as referenced in that answer. The handbook is probably meant to be a more readable introduction, and thus doesn't cover everything.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/tree/master/pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** It's mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.10) as well.

Not in the docs, but it's [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/01/16/announcing-typescript-1-4.aspx).

> #### Type Aliases
>
> You can now define an alias for a type using the type keyword:
>
> ```
> type PrimitiveArray = Array<string|number|boolean>; 
> type MyNumber = number; 
> type NgScope = ng.IScope; 
> type Callback = () => void;
> ```
>
> Type aliases are exactly the same as their original types; they are simply
>   alternative names. You can use these aliases to better document your
>   code and aid readability.

Comment: Good link.  I've been looking at the "docs" on:  http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook  Will swap to using the github repo.  Thanks.  \*edit\* ah and good they have a [TODO to document abstract classes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#8-classes)... which makes much more sense than "silence"  :)

Answer (score 1):

It's called **Type Aliases** to make your code more readable, and you can use it like this:

```
type PrimitiveArray = Array<string|number|boolean>;
type MyNumber = number;
type NgScope = ng.IScope;
type Callback = () => void;
```

Comment: Brtill, thanks.  Where did you learn that from?  Was it another language that on "playing with" `type` in TypeScript you realised works the same way?

Comment: Ok I see it in the [1.4 sneek peak](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/18/what-s-new-in-the-typescript-type-system.aspx)