# What is the TypeScript equivalent of "PropTypes.oneOf" (restrict a variable to subset of values)

Tags: javascript, typescript

In React I can restrict a variable to subset of values, like

```
PropTypes.oneOf(['Home', 'About']),
```

How do I do that in TypeScript?

*PS: I am not using TypeScript with React.*

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can combine static strings (or any regular type) by defining a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
type SomeType = 'Home' | 'About';
```

Or within an interface:

```
interface SomeType {
  prop : 'Home' | 'About';
}
```

And of course you can combine other types as well:

```
type SomeType = string | boolean;
```

Comment: TypeScript's manual refers to these as [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Comment: What if the type is an interface itself. For example, `grid?: Grid;` and `export type Grid = {
    xs?: ColValueType[],
    sm?: ColValueType[],
    md?: ColValueType[],
    lg?: ColValueType[]
}`

Comment: `keyof InterfaceType`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `enum`.

> Enums allow us to define a set of named constants. Using enums can make it easier to document intent, or create a set of distinct cases.

#### enum vs union-type

- Union types are a compile time concept
- Enums are real objects that exist at runtime
- You can iterate over an enum
- ... see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275832/typescript-has-unions-so-are-enums-redundant)

#### Example with enums:

```
enum PostStatus {
    DRAFT = "DRAFT",
    READY = "READY",
    PUBLISHED = "PUBLISHED",
}


class Post {
    constructor(private status: PostStatus) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

const myPost = new Post(PostStatus.DRAFT);

console.log(myPost);

function doStuff(postStatus: PostStatus) {
    switch (postStatus) {
        case PostStatus.DRAFT: 
            console.log('Still working on it');
            break;
        case PostStatus.PUBLISHED:
            console.log('Done.');
        break;
        default:
            console.log('Other ...');
    }
}
```

#### Example with union type:

```
type PostStatus = "DRAFT" | "READY" | "PUBLISHED";


class Post {
    constructor(private status: PostStatus) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}

const myPost = new Post("DRAFT");
console.log(myPost);

function doStuff(postStatus: PostStatus) {
    switch (postStatus) {
        case "DRAFT": 
            console.log('Still working on it');
            break;
        case "PUBLISHED": 
            console.log('Done.');
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Other ...');
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also convert enums to be only available on compile time by adding a `const` before `enum`

Comment: @lumio what's the advantage

Comment: this is not even using react PropTypes. so the question is completelly wrong

Comment: @useless read OP question again, he's asking how to do it in Typescript not react PropTypes, he's not even using React

Answer (score 6):

Only one type among several one is a union type, and in your case a union of [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).

You can convert an array of string literals into a union of string literals as follow:

[If you do have a const array or string you can define a type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUzAVwDIEtowLwwNoBEAEiIgQDQwECCARiMlAQLowCGEMokUA3ALAAoKAE8ADgnhJkAOTaIcMURJAAzKSgzQ8KOLQQAnVgHpjVEmRgAfKnQZMhQA):

```js
const menuList = ["Home", "About"] as const;
type menuName = typeof menuList[number] // "Home" | "About"
```

[If you do already have a type with the array just do:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAthB2BXAMgSwM7CgXigbQCIAJAezgIBooCBBAIxMWAIF0BuAWAChRJYFEASWAQYOfkjSY8SGHQgAnFkA)

```js
type menuList = ["Home", "About"];
type menuItem = menuList[number] // "Home" | "About"
```

Comment: I don't understand where `number` comes from. It works, I just don't understand why.

Comment: `number` is just the type like `boolean` or `string`. Meaning the type of the items in the Array reachable using a key of `number` type

Comment: but im getting a tsc typecheck error :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using an enum type, react proptypes and typescript props

```js
export enum AppPage {
  Home = 'Home',
  About = 'About',
}
export MyComponentProps = {
  page: AppPage
}
export MyComponentPropTypes = {
  page: PropTypes.oneOf<AppPage>(Object.values(AppPage)).isRequired
}

export MyComponent = (props:MyComponentProps) => {
  return <div></div>
}

MyComponent.propTypes = MyComponentPropTypes
```