# Typescript equivalent of PropTypes.oneOf, from existing variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I know that this has been asked-and-answered in [What is the TypeScript equivalent of "PropTypes.oneOf" (restrict a variable to subset of values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248807/what-is-the-typescript-equivalent-of-proptypes-oneof-restrict-a-variable-to-s), but I have a case where I don't feel like the answer solves my issue yet.

I am working on converting a project from JavaScript to Typescript. In one React component, a JSON file is imported. One of the props in the component must be one of the keys of this JSON:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import myData from "./myData.json"

const dataKeys = Object.keys(myData)

function MyComponent({myType, ...}) { ... }

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  myType: PropTypes.oneOf(dataKeys).isRequired,
  ...
}
```

I now want to convert MyComponent into Typescript, so I'm going to remove PropTypes and create a Props interface based off of the existing propTypes. The thing is, I am unsure how to convert `PropTypes.oneOf` which is built off of an existing variable, especially one that depends on an import of a JSON file. Normally, I would use a union of string literals or an enum type. What are my options in this case?

Yes, I have `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` enabled in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I tried `type myPropType = keyof typeof myData` which at first seemed to work: `myPropType` is a union of all the key strings. But when I use this type in a component interface it does not typecheck correctly. On usage, the compiler hints tell me that prop has type 'string' | 'number' | 'symbol'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `iconNames` is an array, this StackOverflow answer should help: [Typescript derive union type from tuple/array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251664/typescript-derive-union-type-from-tuple-array-values)

Basically, when you define `iconNames`, define the type along with it:

```
const iconNames = ['plus', 'arrow', 'trash'] as const;
type IconNamesType = typeof iconNames[number];
```

Comment: I had made an edit to my question to change `iconNames` to `dataKeys`, which is indeed a string array. I had copied over actual production code and forgotten to anonymize that particular line...my bad. Anyway, I'm happy to hear that this feature was recently added to Typescript. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry....I just realized that this answer won't help in my case, because I'm using `Object.keys()` to build the array from an import of another file. Const contexts can't be used with these "dynamic arrays", it can only be used with a static array literal.