# What is the difference (pros/cons) between using an enum or a union of string literals type alias?

Tags: typescript

What are the pros and cons of using an enum vs a type alias as below?

```
const enum LanguageEnum {
  English,
  Spanish
}

type LanguageAlias = "English" | "Spanish";

let l: LanguageAlias = "English";

let la: LanguageEnum = Language.English
```

The goal of using the enum is to enumerate the possible values for a type. But doesn't the union of string literals also enumerate the possible types?

I've always found these TS enums to be so weird.

Comment: Related: [Typescript has unions, so are enums redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40275832/215552)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript has unions, so are enums redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275832/typescript-has-unions-so-are-enums-redundant)