# TypeScript integer enum objects can be assigned any value

Tags: typescript

I have enum as follows:

```
const enum Mode {
  Add = 1,
  Edit = 22,
};

let currentMode: Mode = 222222;
```

My Point is why it is considered a valid code. It should throw compile error on a compilation but it is not.

When we use an enum with Java or C# it enforces us to provide proper value.

Please share thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

According to [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html):

> Enums allow us to define a set of named constants

i.e. enum is not a limited set of options, it's just a list of constants.

The code from your question:

```
const enum Mode{
    Add=1,
    Edit=22
}
let currentMode:Mode=222222;

let add: Mode = Mode.Add
```

will be compiled to the following JavaScript:

```js
"use strict";
let currentMode = 222222;
let add = 1 /* Add */;
```

As you can see there won't be any object created for your `const enum` in JS. TypeScript compiler will place used enum's values at the places of usages instead.

As for the enum type in C#. You can do the same thing. Code listed below is valid C# code:

```cs
public enum Mode
{
    Add = 1,
    Edit = 2
}
...
Mode mode = (Mode)123;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### use string enums or union types instead

The behavior of numeric enums that you describe **is as intended** [as Typescript's bossman himself declares](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38294#event-3305063822). See [Issue 26362](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26362) for details.

If you want value safety (only valid underlying values are allowed) or true type safety, you'll have to use other options such as:

- Union types (value-safe)

  ```
  type Mode = 'Add' | 'Edit'
  ```
- String enums (type-safe)

  ```
  enum Mode {Add = 'add', Edit = 'edit'}
  ```

For an explanation of the above two options, and for more options, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55459814/8910547).