# Type-safe Enum Dictionaries in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like `dirVectors[Turn.Straight]` to fail at compile-time.

```js
enum Direction {
    Up,
    Down,
    Right,
    Left,
}

enum Turn {
    Clockwise,
    Counterclockwise,
    Straight,
}

const dirVectors = {
    [Direction.Up]: [0, 1],
    [Direction.Down]: [0, -1],
    [Direction.Right]: [1, 0],
    [Direction.Left]: [-1, 0]
} as Record<Direction, [number, number]>;
```

I'm assuming the reason `dirVectors[Turn.Straight]` is OK is because they're both numbers, with `Straight =  2`, which is a subset of `Direction {0,...,3}`. When I assign a unique string to each enum's value, it does fail at compile-time. However, **is it possible to get the compile-time error without going the string route?**

Comment: If two enum entries has the same value, they can be used interchangeably to index a `Record`. I don't think there's anyway to change that without assigning each enum entry a globally unique value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign values to Enum, it works as expected:

```js
enum Direction {
  Up = 'Up',
  Down = 'Down',
  Right = 'Right',
  Left = 'Left'
}

enum Turn {
  Clockwise = 'Clockwise',
  Counterclockwise = 'Counterclockwise',
  Straight = 'Straight'
}

const dirVectors = {
  [Direction.Up]: [0, 1],
  [Direction.Down]: [0, -1],
  [Direction.Right]: [1, 0],
  [Direction.Left]: [-1, 0]
} as Record<Direction, [number, number]>

dirVectors[Direction.Up] // compiles
dirVectors[Turn.Straight] // does not compile
```

Question is, do you really need Enum? Are you using anything from Enum which union types does not provide?
See if following works for you:

```js
type Direction = 'Up' | 'Down' | 'Right' | 'Left'

type Turn = 'Clockwise' | 'Counterclockwise' | 'Straight'

const dirVectors: Record<Direction, [number, number]> = {
  Up: [0, 1],
  Down: [0, -1],
  Right: [1, 0],
  Left: [-1, 0]
}

dirVectors['Down'] // compiles
dirVectors['Straight'] // does not compile
```

Comment: The question asked `However, is it possible to get the compile-time error without going the string route?`

Comment: Yes, included other approach!

Comment: I always assumed enums were preferred over union types because of namespaces and just the universal prevalence of them in other languages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275832/ goes into depth as to why that's not the case. I'll start using union types. Thanks!