# How can I define a type that "implements" an interface?

Tags: typescript

Classes can implement interfaces:

```
interface ClockInterface {
    currentTime: Date;
}

class Clock implements ClockInterface {
    currentTime: Date;
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
}
```

How can I define a type that "implements" an interface? I don't understand why the following does not work, as it looks completely reasonable to me:

```
type DigitalClock implements ClockInterface = {
    currentTime: Date;
    somethingDigital: any;
}
```

Comment: That type is simply the interface. You can extend interfaces from other interfaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "type" reserved word in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364693/what-is-the-type-reserved-word-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
type DigitalClock = ClockInterface & {
    somethingDigital: any;
}
```