# Getting this error - Expected Comma, got Some(Str { value: Atom('./type.ts' type=dynamic), has_escape: false })

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, deno

Getting error -

```
error: Expected Comma, got Some(Str { value: Atom('./type.ts' type=dynamic), has_escape: false }) at file: <home>/jozty/Fae/equals.ts:4:17
```

Importing `type.ts` in `equals.ts`. It is giving this when `type` function is exported default, it works fine otherwise. This error is occurring only in this `equals.ts`. It is imported default successfully in other files.

**equals.ts**

```
import curryN from './utils/curry_n.ts'
import { Curry2 } from './utils/types.ts'
import { isFunction } from './utils/is.ts'
import type from './type.ts'

function equals(a: any, b: any) {
  if(Object.is(a, b)) return true
  if(type(a) === type(b)) return true
  if(isFunction(a.equals)) {
    return(
         isFunction(a.equals)
      && isFunction(b.equals)
      && a.equals(b)
      && b.equals(a)
    )
  }
}

export default curryN(2, equals) as Curry2<any, any, boolean>
```

**type.ts**

```
import slice from "./slice.ts"
import { AllTypes } from "./utils/types.ts"

export default function type(a: any): AllTypes {
  if(a === null) return 'Null'
  if(a === undefined) return 'Undefined'
  return slice(8, -1, Object.prototype.toString.call(a)) as unknown as AllTypes
}
```

**AllTypes**

```
export type AllTypes = 'Null'
  | 'Undefined'
  | 'Object'
  | 'Number'
  | 'Boolean'
  | 'String'
  | 'Array'
  | 'RegExp'
  | 'Function'
  | 'Arguments'
  | 'Date'
  | 'Error'
  | 'Map'
  | 'Set'
  | 'WeakMap'
  | 'WeakSet'
  | 'Int8Array'
  | 'Uint8Array'
  | 'Uint8ClampedArray'
  | 'Int16Array'
  | 'Uint16Array'
  | 'Int32Array'
  | 'Uint32Array'
  | 'Float32Array'
  | 'Float64Array'
  | 'ArrayBuffer'
```

Comment: Please post the source code of all the files.

Comment: https://github.com/Jozty/Fae - the link for the repository

Comment: [`type` is a keyword in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31364693/1048572). Do not use it as an identifier.

Comment: Oh, what a silly mistake I was doing! Thank you very much.